# understanding cache in Android bitmap Images

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks, surfaceview

Hello I have this code , I tried to adapt it from android examples by google developer pages. Now it is cached but when i enter the cache loop the images are only displayed from cache and images that are not in cache cannot be displayed any ideas how to solve this?.

There is really few things I am probably missing as I am new to programming and to the android API

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView animalView;
    Animal animal;
    private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)
        // findViewById(R.id.root);
        // surfaceView = new OurView(this);
        // relativeLayout.addView(surfaceView);



         // Get max available VM memory, exceeding this amount will throw an
        // OutOfMemory exception. Stored in kilobytes as LruCache takes an
        // int in its constructor.
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

        // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than
                // number of items.
                return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;
            }
        };

        setContentView(new Animal(this));

    }






    public class Animal extends SurfaceView implements
            SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

        // private Bitmap bmp;
        private static final String KEY_COUNT = "count";;
        private Bitmap jeepbackbmp;
        private Bitmap jeepbmp;
        private Canvas canvas;
        private Bitmap scaled;
        private Bitmap background;
        private int clickCount = 0;
        final int[] AnimalsArray = { R.drawable.elephants,
                R.drawable.sable_antelope2560, R.drawable.wildebeest2560x1600,
                R.drawable.olive_babbon2560, R.drawable.plains_zebras2560,
                R.drawable.bush_pig2560, R.drawable.hippo_and_baby2560,
                R.drawable.african_buffalu2560, R.drawable.black_rhinos2560,
                R.drawable.giraffe_family2560, R.drawable.lessermaskedweaver,
                R.drawable.alcelaphus, R.drawable.cheetah };
        private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
        private int pX;
        private int pY;
        private Region jeepbackregion;
        private Region jeepgoregion;
        private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
        private DisplayMetrics mDisplay;
        private Thread mDrawingThread;
        private int width;
        private int height;
        private float newWidth;
        private float newHeight;
        private int mDisplayWidth;
        private int mDisplayHeight;
        private Bitmap backgroundbmp;
        private ImageView mImageView;
        private Bitmap mBitmap;

        public Animal(Context context) {

            super(context);
            mPrefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
            // If we are going to cache the name and gravity
            // Then we better find out when they are changed
            mPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

            // mBitmapHeightAndWidthAdj = mBitmapHeightAndWidth / 2;



            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    AnimalsArray[clickCount], options);

            mDisplay = new DisplayMetrics();
            MainActivity.this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                    .getMetrics(mDisplay);

            mDisplayWidth = mDisplay.widthPixels;
            mDisplayHeight = mDisplay.heightPixels;

            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            width = size.x;
            height = size.y;


            background = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),AnimalsArray[clickCount], 160, 100);
            float Hscale = (float) background.getHeight() / height;
            float Wscale = (float) background.getWidth() / width;
            newWidth = background.getWidth() / Wscale;
            newHeight = background.getHeight() / Hscale;
            scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, (int) newWidth,
                    (int) newHeight, true);

            jeepbackbmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.jeep256right);
            jeepbmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.jeep256);

//          backgroundbmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
//                  R.id.imageView1);

            jeepbackregion = new Region(0, height - jeepbackbmp.getHeight(),
                    jeepbackbmp.getWidth(), height);

            jeepgoregion = new Region(width - jeepbmp.getWidth(), 0, width,
                    height);



//          RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
//          animalView =  new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
//          animalView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.giraffe_family2560));
//          relativeLayout.addView(animalView);




            mSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
            // mSurfaceHolder.setFixedSize(mBitmapHeightAndWidth, height);
            mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

        }

        // ***************************************
        // ************* TOUCH *****************
        // ***************************************
        @Override
        public synchronized boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

            pX = (int) ev.getX();
            pY = (int) ev.getY();

            switch (ev.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                if (jeepbackregion.contains(pX, pY)) {

                    Log.d("AnimalView", "Back Touch Reached");
                    // jeepBack();
                }

                if (jeepgoregion.contains(pX, pY)) {
                    Log.d("AnimalView", "Go Touch Reached");
                    jeepGo();
                }

                // ballFingerMove = true;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                pX = (int) ev.getX() - jeepbackbmp.getWidth() / 2;
                pY = (int) ev.getY() - jeepbackbmp.getHeight() / 2;

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // ballFingerMove = false;
                // dY = 0;
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        // private void jeepBack() {
        //
        // // vb.vibrate(100);
        // // anim = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(MainActivity.this,
        // // true);
        // // jeepbackview.startAnimation(anim);
        // clickCount = -1 + mPrefs.getInt("clicked", 0);
        // if (clickCount < 0) {
        // clickCount = AnimalsArray.length - 1;
        // }
        // mPrefs.edit().putInt("clicked", clickCount)
        // .putBoolean("user", true).commit();
        //
        // if (clickCount >= 0 && clickCount <= AnimalsArray.length - 1) {
        //
        // background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        // AnimalsArray[clickCount]);
        // float Hscale = (float) background.getHeight()
        // / height;
        // float Wscale = (float) background.getWidth()
        // / width ;
        // float newWidth = background.getWidth() / Wscale;
        // float newHeight = background.getHeight() / Hscale;
        //
        // scaled = null;
        //
        // scaled =
        // Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        // AnimalsArray[clickCount]),
        // (int) newWidth, (int) newHeight, true);
        //
        // }
        // }

        private void jeepGo() {

            Log.d("AnimalView", "jeepGO()  Reached");

            clickCount = 1 + mPrefs.getInt("clicked", 0);

            if (clickCount >= AnimalsArray.length -1) {
                clickCount = 0;
            }

            mPrefs.edit().putInt("clicked", clickCount)
                    .putBoolean("user", true).commit();

            Log.d("AnimalView", "Allocating new Bitmap  Reached");
            Log.d("AnimalView", "clicks " + clickCount);

            canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            if (null != canvas) {
                //drawAnimal(canvas);
                addBitmapToMemoryCache(String.valueOf(AnimalsArray[clickCount]), mBitmap);
                loadBitmap(AnimalsArray[(clickCount + 1)], mImageView);
                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }

        }

        public void drawAnimal(Canvas canvas) {

            Bitmap b = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),AnimalsArray[clickCount], 160, 100);
            float Hscale = (float) b.getHeight() / height;
            float Wscale = (float) b.getWidth() / width;
            newWidth = b.getWidth() / Wscale;
            newHeight = b.getHeight() / Hscale;
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    getResources(), AnimalsArray[clickCount]), (int) newWidth,
                    (int) newHeight, true);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(jeepbackbmp, 10,
                    getHeight() - jeepbackbmp.getHeight(), null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(jeepbmp, getWidth() - jeepbmp.getWidth(),
                    getHeight() - jeepbmp.getHeight(), null);

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            mDrawingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Canvas canvas = null;
                    canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    if (null != canvas) {
                        drawAnimal(canvas);
                        mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }
                }
            });
            mDrawingThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if (null != mDrawingThread)
                mDrawingThread.interrupt();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences arg0,
                String arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
            final String imageKey = String.valueOf(resId);

            final Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemCache(imageKey);
            if (bitmap != null) {
                // setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                //mBitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),AnimalsArray[clickCount], 160, 100);

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inPurgeable = true;
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);



            } else {
               // mImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.african_buffalu2560));
               //canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, null);
                drawAnimal(canvas);

                BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(mImageView);
                task.execute(resId);
            }
        }

   }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
            // keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res,
            int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }


    class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {

        public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView mImageView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        // Decode image in background.
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            final Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                    getResources(), params[0], 160, 100);
            addBitmapToMemoryCache(String.valueOf(params[0]), bitmap);
            return bitmap;
        }



    }

    public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null && bitmap != null) {
            mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
            Log.d("AnimalView", "Bitmap added to cache" + key + bitmap);
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
          Log.d("AnimalView", "Get bitmap got as the key to" + key +  mMemoryCache.get(key) );
        return mMemoryCache.get(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the images are considerably large then you will have to step through the displaying of bitmap efficiency articles.  Otherwise, any large photograph you display will certainly cause a memory error upon loading if you just try and load it as is.

Comment: Thanks, got it  working now. the pictures switching now is there any way I can release some memory? from the hip.

Comment: You can put WeakReference<Bitmap> around bitmap references which will signify the system to release those bitmaps when there is a memory concern.  This will still happen automatically but signals that this particular object should be released before memory concerns occur.  Or you can look at doing a release() on those bitmaps when you'd like.